# Как сделать разметку grid для данной галереи?

Tags: css, grid

Друзья, подскажите какие значения прописать для grid-template-columns и grid-template-rows чтоб удобно было располагать элементы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никак, воспользуйтесь `masonry layout`, ходя это будет немного другое скорее всего.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй
grid-auto-flow: dense;